# VS Code - How to change the color of greyed out folder names in explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I'm using [Monokai Pro](https://monokai.pro/vscode) as my color scheme in VS Code. When VS Code greys out the names of the folders that are found in the `.gitignore` file, the text color becomes incredibly difficult to read.

For example, I had the `/node_modules` folder (circled in red) written inside my `.gitignore` file and VS Code would grey out the `node_modules` text in the Explorer.

[image: bad contrast 1]

When I expand the folder, all the sub-folders' names are greyed out but the text is very difficult to read.

[image: bad contrast 2]

I would like to edit the color of the greyed out file names inside the VS Code JSON settings. I'm aware that I can make customizations to a color scheme as found in the [documentation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color). However, I'm not sure which JSON property targets the greyed out file names inside Explorer.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Pro]": {
        // What should I write here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like this is the one:

```
"gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#ff0000"
```

so

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Pro]": {
        "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```